# Bootstrap datepicker is appending one by one for 2 fields at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

In rails 3.2.9, I am using bootstrap's datepicker to display the date. In a single form, I need to display datepicker for 2 fields. 
If I click first field then datepicker will popup. After that if I click 'tab' button then it will popup the second field's datepicker by appending to the first datepicker.
I need to display one datepicker at a time for particular field's `onclick`. If I click 'tab' button then first field's datepicker should be hidden and the second field's datepicker should popup.

Javascript is like below

```
function currentDatePicker(id){
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('#' + id).datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
});
```

}

In views,

```
<%= f.input :start_date, :as=>:string, :label =>"Start Date", :required => false,
  :input_html=>{:readonly=>true, :value=>@user.start_date.blank? ? "" : @user.start_date} %>

<%= f.input :end_date, :as=>:string, :label =>"End Date", :required =>false,
  :input_html=>{:readonly=>true, :value=>@user.end_date.blank? ? "" : @user.end_date} %>

<script type="text/javascript">
 currentDatePicker('user_start_date');
 currentDatePicker('user_end_date');
</script>
```

[image: for more information I have added the image]

Above I have added an image for more information. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you post the part of your code where you call the currentDatePicker function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different ids for  date picker and then use event handling on ids. Hide manualy first datepicker when clicked on 2nd datepicker.
Or use autoclose attribute of datepicker.
$('#from').datepicker( { autoclose: true, startDate: today.getDate.toString() } );
$('#to').datepicker( { autoclose: true, startDate: today.getDate.toString() });

## form and #to are ids.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue. I solved it by doing the following:

```
var pickers = $(".datepicker")
    .datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yy",
        autoclose: true
    })
    .on("show", function(e){
        pickers.not(e.currentTarget).datepicker("hide");
    });
```